# Live ECS logging into Cloudwatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using an ECS task which runs a Docker container to execute some terraform commands.

I would like to logs the results of the terraform commands into Cloudwatch, if possible live. I am using the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#) package of Python 3.

The function I use to output the result of the command is the following:

```
def execute_command(command):
    """
    This method is used to execute the several commands
    :param command: The command to be executed
    :return decoded: The result of the command execution
    """

    logging.info('Executing: {}'.format(command))
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    communicate = process.communicate()
    decoded = (communicate[0].decode('utf-8'), communicate[1].decode('utf-8'))

    for stdout in decoded[0].split('\n'):
        if stdout != '':
            logging.info(stdout)

    for stderr in decoded[1].split('\n'):
        if stderr != '':
            logging.warning(stderr)

    return decoded
```

Which is called the following way:

```
apply_command = 'terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve -no-color {}'.format(plan_path)
terraform_apply_output = utils.execute_command(apply_command)

if terraform_apply_output[1] is not '':
   logging.info('Apply has failed. See above logs')
   aws_utils.remove_message_from_queue(metadata['receipt_handle'])
   utils.exit_pipeline(1)
```

When the terraform command succeed, I can see its output **after** the command has been executed (i.e: see the result of the apply command after the resources have been applied), which is expected by the code.

When the terraform command failed (let's say because some resources were already deployed and not saved in a `.tfstate`), then I cannot see the login and the ECS task quit without error message.

I can see 2 reasons for it:

1. The result of the failed terraform command returns a non-zero code, which means the ECS task exits before outputing the logs into stdout (and so, into Cloudwatch).
2. The result of the failed terraform command is sent to stderr, which is not correctly logged.

What is my error here, and how could I fix it? Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question sounds suspectly familiar to me. Anyway. 
Adding a sleep(10) just before exiting the task will fix the issue.
From AWS support:

> I’ve been investigating the issue further and I noticed an internal
>   ticket regarding CloudWatch logs sometimes being truncated for Fargate
>   tasks. The problem was reported as a known issue in the latest Fargate
>   platform version (1.3.0). [1] Looking at our internal tickets for the
>   same, as you mentioned in the case description, the current workaround
>   to avoid this situation is extending the lifetime of the existing
>   container by adding a delay (~>10 seconds) between the logging output
>   of the application and the exit of the process (exit of the
>   container). I can confirm that our service team are still working to
>   get a permanent resolution for this reported issue. Unfortunately,
>   there is no ETA shared for when the fix will be deployed. However,
>   I've taken this opportunity to add this case to the internal ticket to
>   inform the team of the similar and try to expedite the process. In
>   addition, I'd recommend keeping an eye on the ECS release notes for
>   updates to the Fargate platform version which address this behaviour:
>   -- https://aws.amazon.com/new/
>   -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/document_history.html

"